# php mysql query by link

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to bring the user details by clicking on "detail" in a table (all the rows in the table are from the db) I bring the info to the table with this (code found it somewhere here),

```
<?php foreach ($link->query('SELECT * from data') as $row){  ?> 

<td><?php echo $row['fullname'] ?></td>
```

this works perfect, and on the table I add this.

```
<?php echo '<a href="details.php?AutoID='.$row['AutoID'].'">Details</a>'; ?>
```

now I'm trying to get the details for each user by using the same code in the query I used before but it doesn't work.

```
<?php $id = $_GET['AutoID']; 
foreach ($link->query('SELECT * from data where AutoID=$id') as $row){  ?> 

<td><?php echo $row['fullname'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['phone'] ?></td>
```

Thanks a lot, I hope I explain myself well.

Comment: You are aware that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection, I hope? Please consider using a prepared statement instead of dropping a user-provided value straight into your query without any form of protection.

Comment: Change the single quotes to double quotes. Variables are only expanded inside double quotes.

Comment: But it would be better to use a prepared query.

Comment: `$id = (int)$_GET['AutoID'];` @Barmar no prepared statement needed.

Comment: is this enough @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
$link->query('SELECT * from data where AutoID=$id')
```

to that

```
$link->query('SELECT * from data where AutoID='.$id)
```

BTW. consider use some filter for $_GET params

Comment: Awesome!!! @Bart Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: "consider"? this guy is wide open to SQL injections, if he dont wanna get hacked...